# Autoloader resulting in class not found

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php, autoload

I am trying to include an autoloader in my wordpress project. More specifically, I am developing a plugin that contains a Classes/ directory of all my classes. I want these classes to be accessible by namespace to my wordpress project root and children files/folders.

I feel like my composer.json should take care of the autoloader implementation, although I am still getting a Class not found fatal error. Has anyone else run into this issue? I appreciate any suggestions in advance!

This is what I tried so far:

./composer.json

```
  {
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "Classes\\": "wp-content/plugins/example-plugin/Classes"
            }
        },
        "require": {}
    }
```

then...

`composer install`

./index.php (in wordpress root)

```
require_once('./vendor/autoload.php');

$foo = new \Classes\MyService();

var_dump($foo); //Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Classes\MyService' not found
die();
```

./wp-content/plugins/example-plugin/Classes/MyService.php

```
namespace Classes;

class MyService {
```

Comment: Wouldn't PSR-4 require the file to be `./wp-content/plugins/example-plugin/Classes/Api/MyService.php` (specifically note the `Api` directory)?

Comment: Hi Phil, I appreciate the suggestions, I've made these two changes, still now luck :/ (see edited)

Comment: Have you executed the `dump-autoload` composer task since adding your `autoload` field?

Comment: What happens if you add `require_once __DIR__ . '/wp-content/plugins/example-plugin/Classes/MyService.php';` to the top of your script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed, composer should take care of your dependencies and autoloading. Your configuration also is correct. Let's walk through a check list:

Does your environment look like this?

```
$ tree
.
├── composer.json
├── composer.phar
├── index.php
├── vendor
│   ├── autoload.php
│   └── composer
│       ├── autoload_classmap.php
│       ├── autoload_namespaces.php
│       ├── autoload_psr4.php
│       ├── autoload_real.php
│       ├── autoload_static.php
│       ├── ClassLoader.php
│       ├── installed.json
│       └── LICENSE
└── wp-content
    └── plugins
        └── example-plugin
            └── Classes
                └── MyService.php
```

Does your composer.json look like this?

```
$ cat composer.json
{
    "name": "my/project",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "My Name",
            "email": "my@na.me"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
       "psr-4": {
           "Classes\\": "wp-content/plugins/example-plugin/Classes"
       }
    },
    "require": {}
}
```

Does your implementation look like this?

```
$ cat wp-content/plugins/example-plugin/Classes/MyService.php
<?php
namespace Classes;

class MyService {
}
```

Finally, does your index look like this?

```
$ cat index.php
<?php

require_once('./vendor/autoload.php');

$foo = new \Classes\MyService;

var_dump($foo);
```

If your answer is "Yes" to all of these, have you refreshed your autoloader?

```
$ composer dump-autoload
```

If your answer is "Yes", then create a new directory, download `composer.phar`, run `php composer.phar init`, copy and paste this answer's files into that directory, and try again.

If that works, then `diff` this with your implementation. My guess is, if you get this far, you have a stray character -- possibly Unicode white space -- hiding in one of your files.

Comment: Thanks for the help! your suggestions did the trick for me :) One question though, previously to adding the autoloader, within the `example-plugin` directory I made use of classes such as `\GuzzleHttp\Client` linked by a separate composer.json/autoload.php file located in `example-plugin/functions/api`, fixing the above issue seems to have broken the existing autoloader, any ideas why this might be and how I would be able to sustain the existing functionality?

Comment: You can either move your autoload definition into the composer.json of the api subdirectory, or you can move its autoload into your new composer.json, or you can ensure the respective code paths use the correct autoload.php. However it shakes out, it's best to have all your code agree to use the same composer.json.

Comment: I'm confused. Just to clarify, the GuzzleHttp\Client is a dependency installed by composer, not a class that I wrote. It lives within the `vendor` directory within the `example-plugin/functions/api` which is the same location of the composer.json file local to the api directory. I tried moving the psr-4 definition to that file with no success... not sure how to make both `/vendor` classes and private classes work simultaneously

Comment: I see. So you have one composer.json file, in the api sub-directory. You can indeed have your own PSR-4 custom classes. It sounds like the new autoload clause trounced the former definition. Check the diff?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I need both to work and it seems one prevails. Those files are ignored, so I don't have a diff. I am wondering if I can have more than one psr clause in my composer.json, one pointing the Classes one pointing to vendor..?

Comment: Or better yet, is it possible to autoload all classes in all directories somehow - i.e. wildcard entry?

Comment: Yep, you can have multiple, and you can include recursively. I blogged this a while ago. Does this help? http://cerebriform.blogspot.com/2015/01/psr-4-in-60-seconds.html