# can not find class of 2amigos

Tags: php, yii2

> PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException Class 'Da\QrCode\QrCode'
>   not found

code fires the Err in my TaolistController.php

```
use Da\QrCode\QrCode;
public function actionGenQrcode(){
    $qrCode = (new QrCode($kaSTR))//right here
        ->setSize(250)
        ->setMargin(5)
        ->useForegroundColor(51, 153, 255);
}
```

I've used composer to add 2amigos.

> C:\Users\cyh>composer require 2amigos/qrcode-library:~1.1
>   ./composer.json has been created Loading composer repositories with
>   package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Package operations: 3 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
>     - Installing khanamiryan/qrcode-detector-decoder (1): Downloading (100%)
>     - Installing bacon/bacon-qr-code (1.0.3): Downloading (100%)
>     - Installing 2amigos/qrcode-library (1.1.2): Downloading (100%) Writing lock file Generating autoload files

---

Actually my phpstorm can find this class. I'm using yiiframework.

Comment: What version of Yii are you using ?

Comment: Have you tried their  two special classes to specifically work with the Yii2 framework ? http://qrcode-library.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: The top answer will help you greatly : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065076/autoloader-resulting-in-class-not-found

Comment: @Cedric it `yii2`

Comment: have you installed the extension in the right vendor where your project is check the vendor directory for the exact path as shown in the code `Da\QrCode\QrCode`

Comment: extension for Yii also doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

run the following command using terminal(CMD)

```
composer dump-autoload
```

this command will dumps the autoloaded files

if this not working try to use it like Component

http://qrcode-library.readthedocs.io/en/latest/yii/qrcode-component/

Answer (score 0):

Try install QR Code library using

```
composer require 2amigos/qrcode-library
```

It works for me. Good luck.